# Basic PHP / SOAP error, can't debug

Tags: php, soap

I'm currently having a really frustrating time with some really simple SOAP / PHP at the moment. I've spent about a week trying EVERYTHING I can think of, on multiple different servers with different versions of PHP and they all still throw the same error. Here's the code:

```
function test() {
    $client = new SoapClient('http://xxx', array("login" => "sandbox", "password" => "password"));

    print_r($client->__getFunctions());

    $ap_param = array();

    // it dies here. CheckServiceAvailable is a valid function returned in __getFunctions()
    $result = $client->__soapcall('CheckServiceAvailable', $ap_param);

    if (is_soap_fault($result)) {
        trigger_error("SOAP Fault: (faultcode: {$result->faultcode}, faultstring: {$result->faultstring})", E_USER_ERROR);
    }
}
```

It faults before the error catching can capture anything. Apache logs show the same fault as below:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [s:Processing error] in C:\soap.php:13 Stack trace: #0 C:\soap.php(13): SoapClient->__soapCall('CheckServiceAva...', Array) #1 C:\soap.php(23): test() #2 {main} thrown in C:\soap.php on line 13
```

Without being able to catch the fault I'm totally stuck as to what to do. I don't really want to try nusoap.

Any ideas?

Comment: I tried using nusoap afterall and perhaps the server is the issue..  `Array
(
    [faultcode] => s:Processing error
                    [Errors] => Array
                        (
                            [ErrorInfo] => Array
                                (
                                    [ErrorMessage] => Internal web service error. Please try again later.
                                    [PropertyName] => Processing error
                                )

 `

Comment: personaly, to debbug SOAP WebSerivces, I put logs in the Server, Like that, I can put lot of messages.

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
try
{
  $result = $client->__soapcall('CheckServiceAvailable', $ap_param);
}
catch (SoapFault $e)
{
  echo "Cannot call method CheckServiceAvailable: {$e->getMessage()}";
}
```

Comment: It's usually best to provide more explanation of how your code will help the OP, and other users with the same problem. See [answer] for more information.

Comment: In my case, there's no message. So `$e->getMessage()` is just blank.